# jQuery Draggable widget not working with li inside a ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Maybe am overlooking this, but I can't figure why this is not working.

I'm creating a draggable list in [jquery-ui](/questions/tagged/jquery-ui), using the draggable widged from [jquery-ui](/questions/tagged/jquery-ui), but I can't seem to be able to make the li draggables, what am doing wrong?

**HTML:**

```
<section>
  <ul id="sortable1">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
    <li>item 9</li>
    <li>item 10</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#sortable1 li').draggable({
  containment: 'section',
  cursor: 'move',
  revert: true
});
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: i think you want to use jQuery UI's `sortable` API instead of `draggable`

Comment: Actually no, to simplify I just added 1 ul, but later on I want to be able to let the user sort this items in another container, If I'm not wrong, sortable doesn't allow that, but thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just add following code to script.

```
$( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lyn4ue4v/)**

Answer (score 0):

You need jQuery-ui.js (https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js)

Check this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#sortable1 li').draggable({
    containment: 'section',
    cursor: 'move',
    revert: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<section>
  <ul id="sortable1">
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>item 3</li>
    <li>item 4</li>
    <li>item 5</li>
    <li>item 6</li>
    <li>item 7</li>
    <li>item 8</li>
    <li>item 9</li>
    <li>item 10</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: I don't get it, when I run the snippet, works, I copy it to my project and doesn't, no errors in the console, nothing. I have imported jquery, and jquery-ui.js

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the mistake is somewhere else in my project, I created a test project and it works, apologies, my mistake.